# Help identifying this landmark and road in "Los Angeles 1940s, Residential Area in color"

Tags: identify-this, los-angeles, landmarks

The [NASS](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1W8ShdwtfgjRHdbl1Lctcw) video [Los Angeles 1940s, Residential Area in color [60fps, Remastered] w/added sound](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt-xhtjOReM) is a processed version of this [archived footage](https://archive.org/details/pet1182r5la).

Starting at about `02:18` a movie camera points backwards from a vehicle driving down a road, pointed at the car behind but also showing few buildings and mountains in the background.

However on the left there is a large, notable building of some cubically-shaped classical architectural style with a large domed roof and possibly some large sculptures of human figures. It feels like it might be a religious building or a mausoleum.

It certainly looks like it might still be around an notable as a Los Angeles landmark.

Is it possible to identify this building and by extension the name of the road being driven on in this video?

For reference, there's a little bit more about NASS in PetaPixel's [Colorized Footage of San Francisco Taken Four Days Before 1906 Fire](https://petapixel.com/2022/04/13/colorized-footage-of-san-francisco-taken-four-days-before-1906-fire/)

---

[image: screenshot from "Los Angeles 1940s, Residential Area in color (60fps, Remastered) w/added sound" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt-xhtjOReM]

[image: detail of screenshot from "Los Angeles 1940s, Residential Area in color (60fps, Remastered) w/added sound" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt-xhtjOReM]

Comment: just asked in Aviation SE [Who put a model of the Space Shuttle at the Portal of the Folded Wings Shrine to Aviation in Los Angeles Ca?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/94044/14213)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Portal of the Folded Wings Shrine to Aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_of_the_Folded_Wings_Shrine_to_Aviation):

> The **Portal of the Folded Wings Shrine to Aviation** is in [Los Angeles, California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles,_California). The shrine is a 75-foot-tall (23 m) structure of marble, mosaic, and sculpted figures and is the burial site for fifteen pioneers of [aviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation). Designed by [Kenneth A. MacDonald Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_A._MacDonald_Jr.) and sculptor, Federico Augustino Giorgi, it was built in 1924 as the entrance to Pierce Brothers [Valhalla Memorial Park Cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valhalla_Memorial_Park_Cemetery)

[image]

([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Folded_Wings_Shrine_portal.jpg); Gareth Simpson; CC-BY-2.0)

Comment: Excellent research, Franck. How did you locate it?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I've been to LA a few times. At first I thought it was the observatory but the observatory has a circular base and a higher dome

Comment: I _grew up_ in LA, and the best I could come up with was the dome at the Wilshire Boulevard Temple, also a miss. Searching by the image on Google didn't help. How did you search?

Comment: with a replica of the Space Shuttle as well! https://goo.gl/maps/ADc9HVJJWKEJN4LK8 So that makes this Cahuenga Blvd? I lived in LA a while myself but I suppose didn't pay too much attention to the cemeteries, except of course for that Hollywood Forever sign on Santa Monica https://goo.gl/maps/Mqo7jhEVs2j8NSk59

Comment: Has the dome been retiled recently?  @uhoh I believe it's Maple St.

Comment: @phoog yes I think your right about the street https://goo.gl/maps/YA9EyJ1mxoq6xhPCA

Comment: @phoog It appears that the arches have been redesigned since then as well.  In the OP, the arches are more pointed at the top, and have a series of smaller arches at the roof-line (below the dome) which aren't there in the modern photo.  I guess some of this was reworked at some time?

Comment: There was some restoration work done after the 1994 earthquake, which might account for the differences.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt fyi I've just asked in Aviation SE [Who put a model of the Space Shuttle at the Portal of the Folded Wings Shrine to Aviation in Los Angeles Ca?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/94044/14213)